# End of file on 19 min from start

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to make like a youtube radio. It's infinity looping video(2 second) and one audio stream(radio). Always after 19 minutes, I getting an error. Does anyone know resolve for that? [image]

UPD:
command: `ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i video.mp4 -i http://127.0.0.1:3000/stream -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -filter_complex [0:v]fps=25,format=yuv420p -b:v 4500k -q:v 3 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/KEY`

Comment: Need to see your command to be able to make any suggestions.

Comment: @llogan added command

Comment: Show the log from the command. The top 100 lines or so will suffice. Copy and paste the text. Do not make an image of the text.

Comment: @llogan https://pastebin.com/7nPTzZzB

Comment: @llogan same result. on 19 min crashed

Answer (score 0):

Looks like bug [#7547 ffmpeg quits with av_interleaved_write_frame message](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7547).

Comments indicate it may be an issue with librtmp. Your ffmpeg has been compiled with `--enable-librtmp`, so it may be affected. Using the built-in FFmpeg RTMP support may avoid this issue.

Recompile without `--enable-librtmp` (omit `--with-rtmpdump` if using Homebrew), or download an already compiled build from [Evermeet](https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/) and try that.

Comment: So if it was installed via brew,  I should exec `brew install ffmpeg --with-rtmpdump`?

Comment: @AndreyKadnikov I don't have any Apple computers so I have never used Homebrew, but you should **avoid** `--with-rtmpdump`. I don't know if the standard Homebrew build script for ffmpeg adds `--with-rtmpdump` by default or not.